# Create a tensorflow dataset based on a "multi-input"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

#### Problem

Create a `tf.data.Dataset` object from a numpy array that contains multiple `X` array.

#### Explaination

This is the model that I'm using, some layers eliminated for reduce the image:[image: Model]

As you can see, the model contains two different input:

- The data itself (shape [Batch, 730, 1])  (from now called `x_train`)
- The timestamp (shape [Batch, 730, 3]) (from now called `ts_train`)

The problem that I'm aiming to solve is a timeseries forecast.
The `x_train` contains a single feature.
The `ts_train` contains three features that rappresent Year,Month,Day of the misuration.

I can fit/evaluate/predict the model without any particular problem.
Example of `fit`:

```py
model.fit(
    [x_train, ts_train],
    y_train,
    batch_size=1024,
    epochs=2000,
    validation_data=([x_test, ts_test], y_test),
    callbacks=callbacks,
)
```

Example of `predict`:

```py
model.predict([x_test[0].reshape(1, window, 1), ts_test[0].reshape(1, window, 3)])
```

However, i can't understand how to cast the `numpy` array that rappresent my dataset into a tensorflow dataset.

Using the following code:

```py
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x_train, ts_train], y_train)
```

I'll receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

How can I cast my  `2 x -> 1 y` into a `tf.data.Dataset` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using tuples like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x_train = np.random.random((50, 730, 1))
ts_train = np.random.random((50, 730, 3))
y_train = np.random.random((50, 5))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((x_train, ts_train), y_train))

for (x, t), y in ds.take(1):
  print(x.shape, t.shape, y.shape)
```

```
(730, 1) (730, 3) (5,)
```

And here is an example model:

```py
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((730, 1))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((730, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input1)
y = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input2)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, y])
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(outputs)
model = tf.keras.Model([input1, input2], outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(ds.batch(10), epochs=5)
```

Comment: Thank you! The solutions seems to work but the model return a `ValueError` after the first epoch:  `ValueError: Input 1 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 730, 3), found shape=(730, 3)`. Seems that the problem is related to the time layer of the `test` dataset. If i remove the validation, it works. Probably cause I have less example than the batch size ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your whole model. Use the model example I posted as a guide.

Comment: The problem was the batch of the test dataset. Solved using ds_test.batch(len(y_test)) cause i user very few example.